# Preparing database for Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an existing MS SqlServer and I want to add new database to it with Entity Framework Code First approach in MVC 4 project.

First, few lines of code:
Global.asax

```
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<IncidentData.IncidentContext>(new IncidentData.IncidentDbInitializer());

            using (var a = new IncidentData.IncidentContext())
            {
                a.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

            }

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IncidentContext"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected void Application_End()
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IncidentContext"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

IncidentDbInitializer.cs:

```
 public class IncidentDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<IncidentContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(IncidentContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            // add some data
            context.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
```

IncidentContext.cs

```
  public class IncidentContext : DbContext
    {
        public IncidentContext()
            : base()
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        //some code
         }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the seed method is not called. I think that's because I didn't configure SQL server, because I once got it working but it was quite time ago and now I need to prepare document how to set it up.

What should I do in order to enable EF to create new database?

I've tried:

1. Preparing only login on the server - then it lacks a DB user and EF can't create DB.
2. Creating DB, adding a user and assigning it to previously created login, then deleting DB - EF creates DB, but does not call seed method, so it's empty. OnModelCreating gets called.

What is the right practise in that case? What credential should I give to this SQL login so that it could create a DB?

As far as I can remember when I got it to work recently, I just checked everything and it worked, but now even that does not do the job. Since it worked, I think the code is fine, but configuration is ekhm flappy :)

Comment: What do we talk of? A small tool running locally - good. A serious real large database - people will KILL you for assuming your program can create a database, that is the DBA / Infrastructure teams job, and they give you the password to use for your program, which please also comes with a config tool because no, automatic migrations totally violate every best practice written in the last 50 years.

Comment: So the database exists but the seed method is not being run?

Comment: Currently it's just a demo of new functionality for bigger system and I need to add one new database to existing SQL Server. It's not production.

But still, I can write a SQL Script that will seed DB since it gets created, but it's more about: why seed method doesn't get called? Is the problem on the server side or in the code?